# How to interpret an error with summarise() column?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I'm running some code using a package installed from devtools, which I've never used. The code is below. Basically, I'm trying to calculate `language entropy()` using proportions.

```
data<-data%>%mutate(Participant.number=as.numeric(Participant.number))%>%na.omit()

exposure<- languageEntropy(data,Participant.number, L1_exposure_proportion,L2_exposure_proportion,L3_exposure_proportion,L4_exposure_proportion,L5_exposure_proportion,contextName = "General Exposure")
```

I'm terrible with troubleshooting in R and I can't seem to figure out this error:

> Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `sum`. ℹ `sum = sum(value, na.rm = T)`. x invalid 'type' (character) of argument ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Participant.number = 1. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I don't really understand where the 'invalid type (character)' comes from, but when clicking the 'show traceback' button, it says that there's an issue with the dplyr package. I'm quite an amateur when it comes to programming, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What package does the `languageEntropy` function come from? Please include any relevant `library()` calls in your question so we can understand what you're trying.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Run `rlang::last_error()` in your console and providing that full trace will help both you and use see what went arwy and help you get better at trouble shooting.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Try
`dplyr::summarise` instead just `summarise` , sometimes it’s happening to me also , I assume the `base` R function is used instead of `dplyr`.

Comment: Hi, the weird thing is that the object I used (languageEntropy) doesn't come from dplyr which is why I'm really confused.